# List all occurs of a value in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> playersInArenas = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

How can I search for all strings (in left column) where Integer (right column) is for example 5?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **loop** and compare the value on each iteration:

```
// declaring map
Map<String, Integer> playersInArenas = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
playersInArenas.put("A", 5);
playersInArenas.put("B", 4);
playersInArenas.put("C", 5);

// "searching" strings
for (Entry<String, Integer> e : playersInArenas.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getValue() == 5) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
    }
}
```

**Note:** Instead of printing the *key* you could store it, or do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    playersInArenas.values().retainAll(Collections.singleton(5));
    Set<String> strings = playersInArenas.keySet();
```

Comment: I'd "+1" this for the elegant solution, but ... the original map is modified here, which should either be avoided or explicitly be pointed out...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could also use the brand new [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API.

```
Set<String> set = playersInArenas.entrySet()
                                 .stream()
                                 .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 5)
                                 .map(e -> e.getKey())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

What it does is:

- get a `Stream` of all the entries of your map
- apply a filter to only get the entries that have the value 5
- map each entry to its key
- collect the result in a `Set`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for each loop that iterates through the maps key set:

```
Map<String, Integer> playersInArenas = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
playersInArenas.put("hello", 5);
playersInArenas.put("Goodbye", 6);
playersInArenas.put("gret", 5);
for(String key : playersInArenas.keySet()){
    //checks to see if the value associated with the current key
    // is equal to five
    if(playersInArenas.get(key) == 5){
        System.out.println(key);            
    }
```